# Using Java SE Endpoint with Embedded Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, jax-ws

I have a JAX-WS web service exposed through the simple Endpoint interface ([example](http://java.dzone.com/articles/jax-ws-hello-world))

If I understand the API correctly, as an alternative to directly calling Endpoint.publish (which uses the Sun's HTTP Server), we can:

1. Create the Endpoint --> `Endpoint e = Endpoint.create(impl);`
2. Publish the Endpoint ---> `e.publish(context);`

Can I use this `e.publish(..)` API to publish to an embedded tomcat server? ([example](http://java.dzone.com/articles/embedded-tomcat-minimal))

The [javadoc of the Publish method](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/ws/Endpoint.html#publish%28java.lang.Object%29) is pretty confusing to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although it is more than two years old, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2083707/1127892) to a related question still applies. If you want to deploy to tomcat, no matter whether it is running in embedded mode or normal, you need to package a `war` and place it in the webapps directory.

To be usable with the `publish()` method in the way described in your question, tomcat would have to provide a [Sun HTTP Server Service Provider Implementation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jre/api/net/httpserver/spec/index.html), which it does not. An alternative to Sun's HTTP Server is for example [Jetty](http://jetty.codehaus.org/jetty/).

Comment: Thanks. I followed your clue on Jetty and found Apache CXF (which uses Jetty internally) that works fine. I posted a few other helpful links that I found on this topic to my [blog](http://kpachar.blogspot.in/2012/09/secure-jax-ws-with-apache-cxf-some-links.html)