# Endpoint publish without Java EE server

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws

Having

```
 Endpoint.publish("http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/someplace", someObject);
```

1- There is any case where make sense to use Endpoint.publish out of a Web Container?(e.g. I have seen many people using it in a main process)

2- When we use Endpoint.publish inside a Web Container(so server has its own IP address). Why we have to set IP address instead of using localhost?

```
Endpoint.publish("http://216.123.456.457:8080/someplace", someObject);
```

instead of

```
Endpoint.publish("http://localhost:8080/someplace", someObject);
```

3- Does it make sense to try to publish a Webservice in a different place than localhost(that is actually the server machine executing this)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding question 1, this thread gave me the answer(https://stackoverflow.com/a/2083707/4738368).

For Question 2 & 3, [Publishing a WS with Jax-WS Endpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680600/publishing-a-ws-with-jax-ws-endpoint) clarify it to me.