# Endpoint publish method with domain name (without soap container)in java

Tags: java

Can I use `Endpoint.publish` (in java j2se method) to publish the web service in production environment with domain name( without soap container is there any problems)?

I have one webservice /ws/tk/xml

```
Endpoint.publish("http:://localhost:8888/ws/tkf/xml",WeserviceImpl);
```

like that i published in my local server and it's working fine,

While moving to production server  how to map  domain name like "http://www.test.com" (Sample) can I publish

```
Endpoint.publish("http:://www.test.com/ws/tkf/xml",WeserviceImpl)
```

like this?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are asking here.

Comment: Hi Robert, Sorry for my English(Sentence) I have added some more information can you check please

Comment: Hi Robert, Now i have understand from this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2083500/java-using-endpoint-to-publish-webservice-to-tomcat-server